# invoke-webrequest download image from list

Tags: powershell, invoke, invoke-webrequest

I'm trying to download a SQL list with several URL images and store them in a local directory divided by name. I've already started doing it but I confess I got lost.
I used invoke-webrequest in powershell

Table SQL Express:

| URL | Name |
| --- | --- |
| http://image.pt/redes/imgredes2.aspx?IMG=76680297 | 34983240953 |
| http://image.pt/redes/imgredes2.aspx?IMG=87348217 | 56986755444 |

Result:

- c:\images\34983240953.jpg
- c:\images\56986755444.jpg

Comment: Please copy and paste, as text, your source code into the question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.